# What is #~ in scheme?

Tags: scheme, guile, guix

What does `#~` mean in scheme (guile)?

For example in this snippet from the guix source code:

```
#~(list (string-append "prefix=" #$output))
```

Comment: Where is that line of code from?

Comment: It's a "[G-Expression](https://guix.gnu.org/en/blog/2023/dissecting-guix-part-3-g-expressions/)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding upon @mnemenaut's comment, which set me on the correct track:

According to the [Guix Reference Manual](https://guix.gnu.org/manual/en/guix.html#G_002dExpressions), G-expressions are implemented in the `(guix gexp)` package.

Here is an abstract that describes the `#~` abbreviation, alongside `#$` and `#$@`:

> G-expressions, or gexps, consist essentially of three [syntactic forms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26892992/12821491):
> gexp, ungexp, and ungexp-splicing (or simply: #~, #$, and #$@), which
> are comparable to quasiquote, unquote, and unquote-splicing,
> respectively.

So this abbreviation is not part of the Guile Scheme implementation (R5RS), but of the Guix API. It's no wonder it was so difficult to find in any source related to the language. When working with Guile, it may be worthwhile to merge the [Guile Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/guile.html), the [Guix Reference Manual](https://guix.gnu.org/manual/en/guix.html) and the [R5RS standard](https://conservatory.scheme.org/schemers/Documents/Standards/R5RS/)  into a single HTML file.